# Exposing.NET assembly as COM 101

Tags: .net, com, interop

I have trouble to expose a .NET assembly in COM. It seems that I must be missing some basic step because I think I followed all tutorials and documentation I found as well as common sense, but still when I do (in a test VBScript):

```
Set o = CreateObject("MyLib.MyClass")
```

It keeps saying that the object cannot be created.

Here are the steps I have done:

1. I have simple one method dummy class with no attributes.
2. The class is in a class library which has **"Make assembly COM-visible" ticked** in Visual Studio.
3. The class library is signed.
4. The DLL is registered via **RegAsm.exe** with the **/codebase** parameter (I don’t want / cannot add the DLL to GAC).

Just to be sure, I tried to copy the library to the same directory as the test VBScript, but it does not help.

**Edit:** I should have mentioned that the I can instantiate the class in COM if I put the DLL into GAC.

**Edit:** Resolved.  I don't have a full explanation, but eventually I found out that it was caused by using:

%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\RegAsm.exe

and not the 64-bit version:

%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\RegAsm.exe

I compared the generated registry keys of the two RegAsm's, and they were the same. So guessing that they generate something else than the registry keys.

Comment: What's the exact error?  And what's the stack trace?  I wonder if it finds your DLL (since you used the /codebase parameter) but can't find some other dependent DLL.

Comment: I was going to investigate the error details, but before I did that I already figured that it was because of the wrong version of AsmReg (see my answer below). Also, it used to work in GAC, and the library did have any dependencies. So the most likely root of the problem seemed to be some registration problem anyway.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't have a full explanation, but eventually I found out that it was caused by using:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\RegAsm.exe
```

and not the 64-bit version:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\RegAsm.exe
```

I compared the generated registry keys of the two RegAsm's, and they were the same. So guessing that they generate something else than the registry keys.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is by design on 64-bit operating systems.  A lot of COM components are in-process DLLs and are only available as 32-bit DLLs.  A 64-bit program cannot load any 32-bit code.  To prevent them from malfunctioning, the registry is virtualized; different programs have different views of the registry.

32-bit programs actually see the keys in HKLM\Software\Wow6432\Classes.  64-bit programs see the regular keys.  This automatically avoids COM server mishaps.

.NET servers are unusual in that they can run both in 32-bit and in 64-bit mode, the JIT compiler takes care of that.  What you should normally do is run *both* versions of Regasm.exe.  The one from the Framework folder will register the server for 32-bit programs, the one from the Framework64 folder registers it for 64-bit programs.

Answer (score 2):

you should add several attributes:

for interface:

```
[Guid("4200ead6-8252-412c-8c7e-c3b586ac40d6")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
```

for class:

```
[Guid("9f718717-bc09-48f1-8ab1-00fa3abf4147")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ProgId("MyLib.MyClass")]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I just tried that, but it did not help.

Comment: These attributes are not strictly necessary, but are nice to have because they give you more control. The main thing is to make sure the assembly/class etc has the ComVisible(true) attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Microsoft Fusion Logger http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx to find out why your assembly fails to load (or bind as it is called).